# Ember JS Component - Cannot read property 'currentHandlerInfos' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember Component action method, whenever I try to return an ajax call synchronously either by using `preventDefault()` or `return false`, I get a following error form the console:

> route-action.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 
>   'currentHandlerInfos' of undefined
>      at getRoutes (route-action.js:15)
>      at getRouteWithAction (route-action.js:20)
>      at Class.action (route-action.js:52)
>      at Backburner._join (backburner.js:814)
>      at Backburner.join (backburner.js:529)
>      at Function.run.join (ember-metal.js:4453)
>      at action.js:364
>      at exports.flaggedInstrument (ember-metal.js:4012)
>      at action.js:363
>      at Class. (action.js:333)

Has anyone encountered this issue with Ember before?

Comment: There is a reason that the `a` in `ajax` stands for `asynchronous`. Please include the code throwing the error. Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).